# VSCode zsh: command not found: pipenv after restarting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pipenv

In VSCode I'm editing .py files using virtual environment I created with `pipenv`. My project folder contains Pipfile and Pipfile.lock. Before I was able to execute my .py files properly with this virtual environment, with a command `pipenv run...`. However when I closed and restarted VSCode, I can no longer execute the files. The error I'm encountering is:

```
>>> pipenv run python python_codes/prepare_data/prepare_data.py    
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

[image: tu]

I vaguely remember that before when it was working, the selected shell was not zsh... But I don't remember which one was selected. And i cannot select other shells for some reason(there is only zsh option). Anybody has an idea about how to solve this? I'm a noob to VSCode.

VSCode Version: 1.45.1

Comment: How did you install `pipenv`? Were you using bash before? Had you previously modified the PATH variable in bash's initialization files?

Comment: OS X recently changed their default shell from bash to zsh.

Comment: I installed `pipenv` following this instruction https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/. And yes indeed I ran `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mmiyazaki/Library/Python/3.6/dir"`

Comment: Try adding that same line to `~/.zprofile`. You may need to reboot or at least restart your applications.

Comment: I restarted the VSCode and now the shell is bash. It still says `Workspace contains Pipfile but 'pipenv' was not found. Make sure 'pipenv' is on the PATH.`